# Firebase 2 core module failing to import (web)

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to import the core module from firebase but it looks like something is wrong with what I''m doing. Currently I'm importing it as:

```
import firebase from 'firebase'
```

With this in my app I do not get the app interface, however, if I do:

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app'
```

It does work but I'm missing all the other modules as the database modules, I could by pass it just by adding a couple more of imports but I'd like to import the full app since it's a simpler implementation

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
import firebase from 'firebase/firebase-browser'
```